# How to localize WPF without recompilation? (dynamically loaded XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, runtime

We have a WPF application that is loading a usercontrol at runtime from the deployed `.XAML` file (customer requirement - they want to be able to replace the views entirely).

We would like to localize strings in this XAML file. All `.resx` file based WPF localization approaches I have found on the web seem to require recompilation when the localized values are changed.

How to localize a dynamically loaded XAML usercontrol without needing to recompile the resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20071123214559/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx) seems to provide a markup extensiion that manages localization loaded from XML files.

Syntax:

```
<TextBlock loc:Translate.Uid="3"
    Text="{loc:Translate}"
    Background="{loc:Translate}"
    Width="{loc:Translate}"
    Height="{loc:Translate}" FontSize="18" 
/>
```

It also supports on the fly language selection (no need to reopen the window).